# Python tarfile library - @PaxHeader files

Tags: python, tar

I want to create an archive with Python tarfile library.

I have wanted to pack two directories: `1`, `2`.

But after executing script I get the archive with 3 directories - `1`, `2`, `.`.

In `test.tar.gz\test.tar\.\.\` I have found many files with the same names: `@PaxHeader`.

Strange but when I pack directories via CLI there are not these same files.

1. Can I pack directories without these system files via Python tarfile?
2. What are these files?

**UPDATE**:

I use:

```
with tarfile.open(archive, 'w:gz') as tar:
    tar.add(x, x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this,add format config.

```py
with tarfile.open(archive, 'w:gz', format=tarfile.GNU_FORMAT) as tar:
    tar.add(x, x)
```

As described in [`tarfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.DEFAULT_FORMAT):

> **tarfile.DEFAULT_FORMAT**
>
> The default format for creating archives. This is currently `PAX_FORMAT`.
>
> Changed in version 3.8: The default format for new archives was changed to `PAX_FORMAT` from `GNU_FORMAT`.